# Is there a better way to get a Firebase Document Reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm building a pagination for my Firebase application. I'm using Angular and the library AngularFire. I'm try to get a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) for pagination purpose but my code seems a bit odd. Maybe you know a better solution to get the document reference?

In my component:

```
  posts: any;
  lastPost: any;

   constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(10)).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.posts = actionArray.map(item => {
        return { 
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        }
      })

      this.lastPost = actionArray[actionArray.length-1].payload.doc; // get the docReference
    });
  }
```

Later in the component I have another function that i pass this document reference to load other posts with this doc reference as a starting point:

```
loadOtherPost() {
    this.firestore.collection('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').startAfter(this.lastPost).limit(10)).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.posts = actionArray.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

And in the view:

Show new messages ☀

My questions:

1. there is a better way to do this? I see a lot of code repetition.
2. I need to take care of unsubscribe event to avoid lack of performance?
3. Is possible to use something like `.push()` to the post property like this?

```
  loadOtherPost() {
    this.firestore.collection('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').startAfter(this.lastPost).limit(10)).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.posts.push(actionArray.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        }
      }))
    })
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  What do you mean by "my cost seems a bit odd"?

Comment: Hi Stevenson, I try to explain a little bit

Answer (score 0):

1. ?
2. ?
3. Yes, i discover that is possible! like this:    `this.notes.push.apply(this.notes, newNotes);`